# C# OrderBy on nested object Property

Tags: c#, linq

I'm using reflection to order by list of objects.
I would like to order this list on a property of a nested object.
This is the code in which I get the list, and I do the sorting of the list

```
List<DocumentModel> documentList;

    if (contractid == -1)
        documentList = helpsi.framework.core.CustomerProvider.DocumentModel.getAllDocumentModelListByCustomer(custid, custtypeid);
    else
        documentList = helpsi.framework.core.CustomerProvider.DocumentModel.getAllDocumentModelListGridByContract(contractid);

    if (sord.Equals("asc")) documentList = documentList.OrderBy(x => x.GetType().GetProperty(sidx.ToUpper()).GetValue(x, null)).ToList();
    else documentList = documentList.OrderByDescending(x => x.GetType().GetProperty(sidx.ToUpper()).GetValue(x, null)).ToList();
```

The DocumentModel object has a DocumentModelType property that contains a DocumentStateDesc string property.
Can I sort the list by the DocumentTypeDesc property using reflection? What can I use in the sidx parameter?
Thanks

This is the DocumentModel class

```
    public class DocumentModel : ObjBase
{
    #region Attributi

    private long _id;
    private string _documentModel;
    private long? _documentModelTypeId;
    private long? _documentModelIssuingEntityId;
    private string _documentModelFilename;
    private string _documentModelPath;
    private DateTime? _documentModelStart;
    private DateTime? _documentModelEnd;
    private string _documentModelVersion;
    private long _contractId;
    private string _contractNumber;
    private long _contractTypeId;
    private long _contractStateId;
    private string _contractState;
    private long _documentModelStateId;
    private string _documentModelValoId;
    private DateTime? _documentModelUploadDate;
    private byte[] _documentModelContent;
    private long _documentModelFilter;

    private bool _flagDeleted;
    private long _userId;
    private int _orderDocumentModel = 0;

    private string _placeOfIssue;
    private string _issuingEntity;
    private DateTime? _releaseDate;
    private int? _idOpInsert;
    private int? _idOpId;

    private long? _customerId;
    private long? _customerTypeId;
    private string _customerNumber;
    private DateTime? _documentModelInvalidated;

    private bool _flagValidating;

    private string _fileRemotePath;

    private long? _folderId;
    private string _folderName;

    protected new HELPSI_Database HELPSI_Database = Common.HELPSI_Database.HELPSI_Anag;



    [XmlElement(ElementName = "CODE_DOCUMENT_MODEL_ID")]
    public long CODE_DOCUMENT_MODEL_ID
    {
        get { return _id; }
        set { _id = value; }
    }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "DESC_DOCUMENT_MODEL")]
    public string DESC_DOCUMENT_MODEL
    {
        get { return _documentModel; }
        set { _documentModel = value; }
    }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "CODE_DOCUMENT_MODEL_TYPE_ID")]
    public long? CODE_DOCUMENT_MODEL_TYPE_ID
    {
        get { return _documentModelTypeId; }
        set { _documentModelTypeId = value; }
    }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "CODE_DOCUMENT_MODEL_ISSUING_ENTITY_ID")]
    public long? CODE_DOCUMENT_MODEL_ISSUING_ENTITY_ID
    {
        get { return _documentModelIssuingEntityId; }
        set { _documentModelIssuingEntityId = value; }
    }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "DESC_DOCUMENT_MODEL_FILENAME", IsNullable = true)]
    public string DESC_DOCUMENT_MODEL_FILENAME
    {
        get { return _documentModelFilename; }
        set { _documentModelFilename = value; }
    }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "DESC_DOCUMENT_MODEL_PATH", IsNullable=true)]
    public string DESC_DOCUMENT_MODEL_PATH
    {
        get { return _documentModelPath; }
        set { _documentModelPath = value; }
    }


    [XmlElement(ElementName = "DATE_DOCUMENT_MODEL_START")]
    public DateTime? DATE_DOCUMENT_MODEL_START
    {
        get { return _documentModelStart; }
        set { _documentModelStart = value; }
    }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "DATE_DOCUMENT_MODEL_END")]
    public DateTime? DATE_DOCUMENT_MODEL_END
    {
        get { return _documentModelEnd; }
        set { _documentModelEnd = value; }
    }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "DESC_DOCUMENT_MODEL_VERSION", IsNullable = true)]
    public string DESC_DOCUMENT_MODEL_VERSION
    {
        get { return _documentModelVersion; }
        set { _documentModelVersion = value; }
    }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "CODE_CONTRACT_ID")]
    public long CODE_CONTRACT_ID
    {
        get { return _contractId; }
        set { _contractId = value; }
    }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "FLAG_DELETED")]
    public bool FLAG_DELETED
    {
        get { return _flagDeleted; }
        set { _flagDeleted = value; }
    }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "CODE_USER_ID")]
    public long CODE_USER_ID
    {
        get { return _userId; }
        set { _userId = value; }
    }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "ORDER_DOCUMENT_MODEL")]
    public int ORDER_DOCUMENT_MODEL 
    {
        get { return _orderDocumentModel; } 
        set { _orderDocumentModel = value;} 
    }

    private DocumentModelType _documentModelType;
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "DocumentModelType", IsNullable = true)]
    public DocumentModelType documentModelType
    {
        get { return _documentModelType; }
        set { _documentModelType = value; }
    }

    private DocumentModelState _documentModelState;
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "DocumentModelState", IsNullable = true)]
    public DocumentModelState documentModelState
    {
        get { return _documentModelState; }
        set { _documentModelState = value; }
    }

    private DocumentModelIssuingEntity _documentModelIssuingEntity;
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "DocumentModelIssuingEntity", IsNullable = true)]
    public DocumentModelIssuingEntity documentModelIssuingEntity
    {
        get { return _documentModelIssuingEntity; }
        set { _documentModelIssuingEntity = value; }
    }

    //private DocumentModelFolder _documentModelFolder;
    //[XmlElement(ElementName = "DocumentModelFolder", IsNullable = true)]
    //public DocumentModelFolder documentModelFolder
    //{
    //    get { return _documentModelFolder; }
    //    set { _documentModelFolder = value; }
    //}

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "CODE_DOCUMENT_MODEL_STATE_ID")]
    public long CODE_DOCUMENT_MODEL_STATE_ID
    {
        get { return _documentModelStateId; }
        set { _documentModelStateId = value; }
    }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "VALO_DOCUMENT_MODEL_ID")]
    public string VALO_DOCUMENT_MODEL_ID
    {
        get { return _documentModelValoId; }
        set { _documentModelValoId = value; }
    }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "DATE_DOCUMENT_MODEL_UPLOAD")]
    public DateTime? DATE_DOCUMENT_MODEL_UPLOAD
    {
        get { return _documentModelUploadDate; }
        set { _documentModelUploadDate = value; }
    }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "DESC_DOCUMENT_MODEL_CONTENT")]
    public byte[] DESC_DOCUMENT_MODEL_CONTENT
    {
        get { return _documentModelContent; }
        set { _documentModelContent = value; }
    }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "CODE_DOCUMENT_MODEL_FILTER_ID")]
    public long CODE_DOCUMENT_MODEL_FILTER_ID
    {
        get { return _documentModelFilter; }
        set { _documentModelFilter = value; }
    }

    private long _code_siteId;
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "CODE_SITEID")]
    public long CODE_SITEID
    {
        get { return _code_siteId; }
        set { _code_siteId = value; }
    }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "DESC_DOCUMENT_RELEASE_PLACE")]
    public string DESC_DOCUMENT_RELEASE_PLACE
    {
        get { return _placeOfIssue; }
        set { _placeOfIssue = value; }
    }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "DESC_DOCUMENT_RELEASED_BY")]
    public string DESC_DOCUMENT_RELEASED_BY
    {
        get { return _issuingEntity; }
        set { _issuingEntity = value; }
    }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "DATE_DOCUMENT_RELEASED")]
    public DateTime? DATE_DOCUMENT_RELEASED
    {
        get { return _releaseDate; }
        set { _releaseDate = value; }
    }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "CODE_OP_INSERT_ID")]
    public int? CODE_OP_INSERT_ID
    {
        get { return _idOpInsert; }
        set { _idOpInsert = value; }
    }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "CODE_OP_ID_ID")]
    public int? CODE_OP_ID_ID
    {
        get { return _idOpId; }
        set { _idOpId = value; }
    }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "CODE_CUSTOMERID")]
    public long? CODE_CUSTOMERID
    {
        get { return _customerId; }
        set { _customerId = value; }
    }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "CODE_CUSTOMERTYPEID")]
    public long? CODE_CUSTOMERTYPEID
    {
        get { return _customerTypeId; }
        set { _customerTypeId = value; }
    }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "DATE_DOCUMENT_MODEL_INVALIDATED")]
    public DateTime? DATE_DOCUMENT_MODEL_INVALIDATED
    {
        get { return _documentModelInvalidated; }
        set { _documentModelInvalidated = value; }
    }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "FLAG_VALIDATING")]
    public bool FLAG_VALIDATING
    {
        get { return _flagValidating; }
        set { _flagValidating = value; }
    }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "CODE_CONTRACT_STATES_ID")]
    public long CODE_CONTRACT_STATES_ID
    {
        get { return _contractStateId; }
        set { _contractStateId = value; }
    }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "DESC_CONTRACT_STATES")]
    public string DESC_CONTRACT_STATES
    {
        get { return _contractState; }
        set { _contractState = value; }
    }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "CODE_CONTRACT_TYPE_ID")]
    public long CODE_CONTRACT_TYPE_ID
    {
        get { return _contractTypeId; }
        set { _contractTypeId = value; }
    }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "DESC_CONTRACT_NUMBER")]
    public string DESC_CONTRACT_NUMBER
    {
        get { return _contractNumber; }
        set { _contractNumber = value; }
    }


    [XmlElement(ElementName = "DESC_CONTACT_NUMBER")]
    public string DESC_CONTACT_NUMBER
    {
        get { return _customerNumber; }
        set { _customerNumber = value; }
    }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "CODE_DOCUMENT_MODEL_FOLDER_ID")]
    public long? CODE_DOCUMENT_MODEL_FOLDER_ID
    {
        get { return _folderId; }
        set { _folderId = value; }
    }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "DocumentModelFolderName")]
    public string DocumentModelFolderName
    {
        get { return _folderName; }
        set { _folderName = value; }
    }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "DESC_FILEREMOTEPATH")]
    public string DESC_FILEREMOTEPATH
    {
        get { return _fileRemotePath; }
        set { _fileRemotePath = value; }
    }
    #endregion
  }
```

And this is the DocumentModelType Class

```
public class DocumentModelType : ObjBase
{

    #region Attributi

    private long _id;
    private string _documentModelType;

    private bool _flagDeleted;
    private long _userId;

    protected new HELPSI_Database HELPSI_Database = Common.HELPSI_Database.HELPSI_Anag;


    [XmlElement(ElementName = "CODE_DOCUMENT_MODEL_TYPE_ID")]
    public long CODE_DOCUMENT_MODEL_TYPE_ID
    {
        get { return _id; }
        set { _id = value; }
    }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "DESC_DOCUMENT_MODEL_TYPE")]
    public string DESC_DOCUMENT_MODEL_TYPE
    {
        get { return _documentModelType; }
        set { _documentModelType = value; }
    }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "FLAG_DELETED")]
    public bool FLAG_DELETED
    {
        get { return _flagDeleted; }
        set { _flagDeleted = value; }
    }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "CODE_USER_ID")]
    public long CODE_USER_ID
    {
        get { return _userId; }
        set { _userId = value; }
    }


    #endregion
 }
```

Comment: How does `DocumentModel` look like? Is `sidx` a private property?

Comment: sidx is a string parameter that I pass to the method.

Comment: You mention DocumentModelState, but give code for DocumentModelType.

Comment: Sorry. Edited the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be using `x => x.DocumentModelType.GetType().GetProperty(sidx.ToUpper()).GetValue(x.DocumentModelType, null)` inside `OrderBy` clause. Here `sidx` should be `DocumentStateDesc` as you mentioned that you want order on this column.

Complete code will be like below.

```
List<DocumentModel> documentList;

if (contractid == -1)
    documentList = helpsi.framework.core.CustomerProvider.DocumentModel.getAllDocumentModelListByCustomer(custid, custtypeid);
else
    documentList = helpsi.framework.core.CustomerProvider.DocumentModel.getAllDocumentModelListGridByContract(contractid);

if (sord.Equals("asc")) 
    documentList = documentList.OrderBy(x => x.DocumentModelType.GetType().GetProperty(sidx.ToUpper()).GetValue(x.DocumentModelType, null)).ToList();
else 
    documentList = documentList.OrderByDescending(x => x.DocumentModelType.GetType().GetProperty(sidx.ToUpper()).GetValue(x.DocumentModelType, null)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

One quick and dirty fix is to introduce property in parent class that just returns the property value of another property. Just don't assign XmlElement attribute to it. If the classes are auto-generated you can't change them, but they are probably declared as `partial`, and then you can add this new property in additional class definition.

```
public string DocumentModelType_DocumentStateDesc { get => DocumentModelType.DocumentStateDesc; }
```

But if you want to have a general solution for several properties with several sub-properties then some sort of pathing is required. You could `String.Split` `sidx` on some delimiter like `'\'` or `'.'`, use recursion, and then `OrderBy` the last item in the path.